# Display model error on same popup dialog in MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I am developing MVC4 application which has Index.cshtml (main pg with searching criteria & Search button), _PartialView.cshtml (partial view displaying records with update/delete links), Edit.cshtml (View for updating).

After clicking Update link, popup modal dialog is opened containing Edit view (Edit.cshtml) I applied Required & StringLength attribute to some fields. If some of attributes not fulfilled, i want to display them in same popup. But in controller action method, I am returning View so modal popup disappears & Edit view is opened in div.

My records are displayed as grid in partialView (_PartialView.cshtml) with Update link and javascript function as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail" onclick="editFunc(@item.SrNo)">Update</a></pre>


function editFunc(id) {
var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Home/Edit';
var $buttonClicked = $(this);
var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "SrNo": id },
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
        $('#myModal').css('display', 'block');
        $("#myModal").dialog({
            title: 'Edit Data',
            modal: true,
            bgiframe: true,
            show: 'slide',
            hide: 'slide',
            width: 750
        });
        $('#myModal').dialog("show");
    },

    error: function () {
        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
    }
});
}
```

My Edit.cshtml :

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divPartial", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "CallEditBegin", OnSuccess = "CallUnblock" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   

    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label" style="display:none" >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SrNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" style="display:none">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SrNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SrNo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReaderName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReaderName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReaderName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadDate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
 }
```

My HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(UploadData uploadData)
  {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {

          return View(uploadData);
      }
       else 
      {

          // Processing Logic here

      }
   }
```

My Model class (UploadData.cs) is :

```
public class UploadData
{
    public int SrNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Reader Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Reader Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string ReaderName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Upload Date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Upload Date")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

}
```

Now some filed are required and ReaderName has restiction of min length of 6 characters. If any of the condition not fulfilled below block will be executed.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{

      return View(uploadData);
}
```

But what happened next, my popup dialog disappears & div will be open on main pg displaying error message.
I want to show them on popup itself in front of control.

I am confusing what to do in case of model errors so that they appear in same popup after control.
Please give some advice, what I am missing.....

Answer (score 0):

```
   I have a suggestion to put a div on your layout/view, with a condition  

  <div id="divPartial">
    @if (TempData["ErrorMsg"] != null)
            {
    <"p class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">"@TempData["ErrorMsg"]</p>
    } 
    </div>

    Then On your controller:

       [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Edit(UploadData uploadData)
      {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {

              return View(uploadData);
          }

    else  {
                TempData["ErrorMsg"] = "";

                      foreach (var items in ModelState.Values)
                      {
                          foreach (var er in items.Errors)
                          {
                                
                           TempData["ErrorMsg"] = er.ErrorMessage.ToString() " " + TempData["ErrorMsg"].ToString();
                            }
                            
                        }

                        return View(uploadData);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Can't understand what you are trying to explain. Please see updated question for more detail information.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a suggestion to put a div on your layout/view, with a condition:

```html
      <div id="divPartial">
    @if (TempData["ErrorMsg"] != null)
            {
    <"p class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">"@TempData["ErrorMsg"]</p>
    } 
    </div>
```

> Then on your Controller

```
       [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Edit(UploadData uploadData)
      {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {

              return View(uploadData);
          }

    else  {
                TempData["ErrorMsg"] = "";

                      foreach (var items in ModelState.Values)
                      {
                          foreach (var er in items.Errors)
                          {

                           TempData["ErrorMsg"] = er.ErrorMessage.ToString() " " + TempData["ErrorMsg"].ToString();
                            }

                        }

                        return View(uploadData);
                    }
    }
```